# SDWebImage not working with Firebase storage image download

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-storage, sdwebimage

I am working with one project which uses Firebase storage API and getting some image from Firebase.

Working fine with `NSData` logic with download image from server and show it into my app.

But same thing is not working through `SDWebImage` SDK as I need to combine firebase url in SDWebImage as firebase docs also mention to bind this and use to download images fro. Storage through SDWebImage

Below is my cod ewhixh is not working my app.

```
FIRStoragereference *ref = [[FIRStorage storage] referenceWithPath:myfilepath];

[Cell.imgDetail sd_setImageWithStorageReference:ref placeholderImage:nil completion:^(UIImage *image,

}];
```

> Error : method not found in sd web image

Please help me I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used firebase withSDWebImage and you can use below method for StorageReference

For this Method you need to add one category file for UIImageView

```
#import "UIImageView+FirebaseStorage.h"
```

You can find this file here at [FireBaseUIIOS](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseStorageUI)

```
FIRStorageReference *storageRef = [[FIRStorage storage]
                                           referenceWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Folder/images/%@",<IMAGE_NAME>]];


        [cell.imgDetail sd_setImageWithStorageReference:storageRef
                                       placeholderImage:nil
                                             completion:^(UIImage *image,
                                                          NSError *error,
                                                          SDImageCacheType
                                                          cacheType,
                                                          FIRStorageReference *ref) {
                                                 if (error != nil) {
                                                     NSLog(@"Error loading image: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                                 }
                                             }];
```

Also you can use above @Shafi's method of SDWebImage but for that you need to provide full url of firebase storage like below.

Full URL : `storageRef.fullPath`

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Not getting mention class and its still giving same error .

Comment: Please check provided link properly and do as directed Link : https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseStorageUI add this folder or classes in your project not in POD file and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

FirebaseUi has come up with their own little extension for SDWebImage.

Just add following pod in your Podfile

> pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'

And Use following line of code to cache image with the Firebase Storage Reference.

```
// Load the image using SDWebImage
[imageView sd_setImageWithStorageReference:reference placeholderImage:placeholderImage];
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by implementing the other method of SDWebImage

```
SDWebImageManager.shared().downloadImage(with:"Your Firebase Url", options: .refreshCached, progress: nil, completed: { (image, error, cache, isDownloader, url) in
    if image != nil { 
        YourImageView.image = image       
     }
})
```

This is in Swift but you can implement it in Objective-C.

Here is a link:
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/845

Comment: Sorry but its not working at my end as I have ref of fire base not have direct url so.

Comment: @BhaviDev have you figured how to do this with updating cache

Comment: You need to convert your firebase storage URL into a download URL first.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a `BridgingHeader.h` file to your project with this:

```or-tag-here
#import <FirebaseStorageUI.h>
```

2. Then in your class:

```or-tag-here
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorageUI // <-- don't forget to import this

func getImage() {

    let reference = storageRef.child(imageFileName)

    myImageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "bg"), completion: { (image, error, cacheType, storageRef) in
            //...
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to import the SDWebImage module like this  (Swift)

```
@import SDWebImage
```

Or for Obj-C

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

Comment: Sorry but its already there still its showing method not found.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4 (Working Perfectly)

PLEASE INSTALL THIS PODS FIRSTLY:

```
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'
```

Then in your Xcode 9+:

```
import FirebaseStorage
import SDWebImage
import FirebaseUI


let reference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "your image path")
let imageView: UIImageView = self.imageView
imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference)
```